# VBA Getting info from website

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm writing a code in VBA to enter in a few websites put a date in the search field and then get the number os lists found for that date.

The code works when I'm debuggind pressing F8 key, but when I run the macro it sometimes work sometimes doesn't. When I get the error message, I just press debug and then F5 to continue the macro and it works as it should. The problem always occours in the line with the:

`Call IE.document.GetElementsByID("........")`

The error message is: Run time error '424', The object is required.

I think the problem is with the page not loading, but I'm not sure.

```
Sub PegarDadosListas(data As Date)

Dim contador As Integer

Dim dia As String
Dim mes As String
Dim ano As String

dia = Day(data)
mes = Month(data)
ano = Year(data)

Range("K2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = data

Call Extra(dia, mes, ano)
Call Pontofrio(dia, mes, ano)

End Sub

Sub Extra(dia As String, mes As String, ano As String)

Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

URL = "http://www.extra.com.br/listadecasamento/home.aspx"

IE.Navigate URL

Do While IE.Busy
     DoEvents
Loop

Call IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_PaginaSistemaArea1_ctl04_txtDia").setattribute("value", dia)
Call IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_PaginaSistemaArea1_ctl04_txtMes").setattribute("value", mes)
Call IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_PaginaSistemaArea1_ctl04_txtAno").setattribute("value", ano)
IE.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_PaginaSistemaArea1_ctl04_btnEncontrarLista").Click

Do While IE.Busy
     DoEvents
Loop

Sheets("Plan2").Range("A4") = IE.document.getelementsbyclassname("pagination")(0).innertext
Sheets("Plan2").Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R4C1,R3C1,40)"
Sheets("Plan2").Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=FIND(""pesquisa"",R4C1)"

IE.Quit

Call CopiaeCola(3)

End Sub

Sub Pontofrio(dia As String, mes As String, ano As String)

Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

URL = "http://www.pontofrio.com.br/Site/ListaGerenciadaCasamentoWelCome.aspx"

IE.Navigate URL

Do While IE.Busy
     DoEvents
Loop

With IE

Call .document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_CtrlBuscarLista_txtDia").setattribute("value", dia)
Call .document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_CtrlBuscarLista_txtMes").setattribute("value", mes)
Call .document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_CtrlBuscarLista_txtAno").setattribute("value", ano)
.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_CtrlBuscarLista_btnEncontrarLista").Click

Do While IE.Busy
     DoEvents
Loop

Sheets("Plan2").Range("A4") = IE.document.getelementsbyclassname("pagination")(0).innertext
Sheets("Plan2").Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R4C1,R3C1,40)"
Sheets("Plan2").Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=FIND(""pesquisa"",R4C1)"

End With

IE.Quit

Call CopiaeCola(4)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `getElementById` not `getElementsById`, although your code shows the correct version.

Just because IE is not busy doesn't mean that the page has finished loading. You need to check for

```
If IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Then '4
```

You should also use a `Sleep` method, or some other method to prevent `.Busy` being read constantly.

**Added**: A Win-API call can call be used for the `Sleep` method:

```
Option Explicit

'Declare Sleep API
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal nMilliseconds As Long)

Sub UseIE()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim thePage As Object
    Dim strTextOfPage As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.FullScreen = True
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
        While Not .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE '4
            Sleep 500      'wait 1/2 sec before trying again
        Wend
    End With

    Set thePage = ie.Document
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your answer.
I was using a different code before I was using the:
`Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4`

Aren't they the samething?

I'll chenge mine for something like:

`Do while IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
doevents
loop`

I'm not familiar with the sleep method but I'll look into it!

Thank you

Comment: READYSTATE has the value 4, so these are the same. (Using 4 may be necessary depending on which application you are running the code from.) I've updated my answer to include the Sleep method.

Comment: Thank you!
I'll include the sleep in my code and change it back to readystate!